# Wordpress Automated Posts Creation

Tags: automatic-updates, bulk

I have already read the question on: [Automating Page Creation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/268985/automating-page-creation) and the possible suggestion, but I want to have another discussion here.

So, I am having a python scraper which gets 1000s of results daily, and it is already going well. It then pushes the new results into a WP DB. Now, for each result (which is a player), I want to create a post for it with a very sophisticated design. However, the design is similar for all players but the data just change.

I wanted to know if there is a way in Wordpress now that I can use to maybe create variables in a template file and then just pass the data to those variables during runtime?

My solution that I can see (but didn't test yet) is to create a PHP template in python and then pass the data there from python code and make the python create the page into the DB, which I am not sure if this is the best practice?

However, I am not a Savvy WP editor so I am not sure.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You’re describing a custom post type.

Comment: and post meta. Note that we can't help you write python code, and this isn't a discussion forum, you need to be able to write a _specific_ question that can be answered fully and factually