# Creating 20,000 Posts or Pages using a .csv file?

Tags: plugins, mysql, sql, csv

Here's my challenge: I have a .csv file which contains 20,000 rows of data.

**Each row** contains 5 columns of data on an particular individual.

I need each row (each person) to be populated into a WordPress Page or Post. So, in other words, I need to convert 20,000 rows from a .csv into 20,000 posts or pages (i.e. HTML files).

How would I go about this? Is there a plugin or would you suggest that this is more of a mySQL command?

Any direction gratefully received!

Thanks!

Comment: this answer on a different question has a few different import approaches. hopefully gets you in the right direction: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/268853/118366

Comment: I think you can try this plugin - Import any XML or CSV File to WordPress https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-import/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### **Import posts from a .csv file with WP-CLI**

If our `import.csv` is *tab* delimited, with two columns:

```
Planet Mars     The red planet. 
Planet Earth    Our blue planet.
```

then we can parse it with help of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4286841/2078474), where we use `IFS=$'\t'` instead as tab delimiter:

```
while IFS=$'\t', read col1 col2; \
do \
    echo "$col1|$col2";
done < import.csv
```

Note that the column count must match the file's columns.

Now let's use WP-CLI  to create posts with [`wp create post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/post/create/):

```
while IFS=$'\t', read col1 col2; \
do \
  wp post create \
    --post_title="$col1" \
    --post_content="$col2" \
    --post_author=1 \
    --post_type=post \
    --post_status=publish \
done < import.csv
```

If we have additional meta data, like average distance from the Sun in
astronomical units (au):

```
Planet Mars     The red planet.     1.52
Planet Earth    Our blue planet.    1.00
```

then we can try:

```
while IFS=$'\t', read col1 col2 col3; \
do \
  wp post create \
    --post_title="$col1" \
    --post_content="$col2" \
    --post_author=1 \
    --post_type=post \
    --post_status=publish \
    | xargs -I % wp post meta add % distance_au "$col3"; done < import.csv
```

It would be handy if `wp post create` supported the `meta_input` argument of `wp_insert_post()`.

We could also have written this out with `wp_insert_post()` from a php file with the `wp eval-file` [command](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/eval-file/).

WP-CLI [supports](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/user/import-csv/) importing users from a csv file, but I haven't seen this kind of core feature for posts yet.

We could instead write our own WP-CLI command for csv posts import.

Then there's are plugins, like [WP CLI Import CSV](https://github.com/jeffsebring/wp-cli-import-csv), that seems to have done it already (I'm not related to it and haven't used it).

Note that WP-CLI can [import](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/import/) wxr files, if you can convert your csv file into wxr file(s).

Also note that currently (4.8) WordPress doesn't handle *hierarchical* post types (aka pages) well in the wp-admin backend. All posts, of that type, are loaded at once into the parent selection's dropdown. That doesn't scale well and can result in PHP timeout, when working in the backend! See for example [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/169582/26350). So **go for non-hierarchical post types** (aka posts) in your large imports.